# VBA Runtime Error 91 - Code Issue?

Tags: excel, vba

This has most definitely been asked before but I just want to know what is wrong with my code, as it was working previously and now it has suddenly thrown up a Runtime error 91

```
          Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
          Dim r As Range, rng As Range, snRow As Range, TmRow As Range
          Dim x As Integer, ETRow As Long, LTRow As Long
          Dim TMName As String
          Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          ETRow = 10: LTRow = 10
          ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AG5,C10:L38").ClearContents
          For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
          If Sheets(x).Name <> "Summary" Then
          With Sheets(Sheets(x).Name)
          TMName = Left(Sheets(x).Name, 6)
          With .Range("C:C")
          Set snRow = .Find("Total Staff", LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole)
          End With
          Set rng = .Range("D5", "AH5")
          For Each r In rng
            If InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then
                With Sheets("Summary")
                  .Cells(4, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                    With .Range("C9:F9")
                        Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    End With
    *************ERROR HERE---> .Cells(ETRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "ET", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                    ETRow = ETRow + 1
                End With
                    ElseIf InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then
                     With Sheets("Summary")
                    .Cells(5, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                    With .Range("I9:L9")
                        Set TmRow = .Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    End With
                     .Cells(LTRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "LT", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                    LTRow = LTRow + 1
                End With

            End If
        Next
    End With
End If
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is TmRow being set to a valid value on the previous line? @Gary'sStudent I'm going to have to guess the one with all of the asterisks ***** that says "ERROR HERE".... just a hunch.

Comment: If I comment out that row, then the identical row for LT works just fine, so I am at a loss why ET doesn't work

Comment: both your If and Else if are testing for `"LT"`  I think the IF should be testing for `"ET"`

Comment: It is not a good idea to nest **With** statements. I would remove the inner version, it will be easier to discover any related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy G has mentioned your nested With statement are probably the cause of your issues, I think the code below will help you find the issue if any, also amended the code as per the comment from Scott Craner:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim r As Range, rng As Range, snRow As Range, TmRow As Range
Dim x As Integer, ETRow As Long, LTRow As Long
Dim TMName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ETRow = 10: LTRow = 10
ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AG5,C10:L38").ClearContents
For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(x).Name <> "Summary" Then
        TMName = Left(Sheets(x).Name, 6)
        Set snRow = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Range("C:C").Find("Total Staff", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set rng = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Range("D5", "AH5")
        For Each r In rng
            If InStr(1, r.Value, "ET") > 0 Then
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(4, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                Set TmRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("C9:F9").Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(ETRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "ET", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                ETRow = ETRow + 1
            ElseIf InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
                Set TmRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("I9:L9").Find(TMName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(LTRow, TmRow.Column) = Left(r.Value, InStr(1, r.Value, "LT", vbTextCompare) - 1)
                LTRow = LTRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Xabier, Thank you for your help it looks a-lot better but now I am getting the following error "Compile Error Invalid or unqualified reference" isn't this due to the **.range** requiring a WITH statement to be added for it to be reference

Comment: Hi @PhpNewbie I've updated my answer, I believe I missed qualifying the .Range with a Sheet, but no it does not require qualifying with a WITH statement... Try my updated answer, but if you get an error, please could you let me know where that error is being triggered? As I haven't looked at your code that in depth, I simply qualified the references without your nested WITH statements...

Comment: Hello Xabier, I am now get a runtime error 91 on line underneath ** ElseIf InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then**  which is **Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, r.Column - 1) = Sheets(Sheets(x).Name).Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value**

Comment: Can I just say thank you for this Xabier and everyone who is trying to help, it is appreciated and I am still learning VBA so all this help is amazing.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code and double checked that all your variables contain acceptable values?

Comment: Sorry when I tried it on a different laptop it works fine, does anyone know why this happens, both excels are the same and updated to the latest updates. Very Strange